# How to know menu open or not in swrevealviewcontroller in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2

I have made one app in ios. I have use swrevealviewcontroller for menu.I need keyboard disapper when menu open or not. So how to recognize menu is open or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for **jonkykong/SideMenu**

implement UISideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate

```
func sideMenuDidAppear(menu: UISideMenuNavigationController, animated: Bool) {
    print("SideMenu Appeared! (animated: \(animated))")
}

func sideMenuDidDisappear(menu: UISideMenuNavigationController, animated: Bool) {
    print("SideMenu Disappeared! (animated: \(animated))")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check the status of the SWRevealViewController in your code, check the `frontViewPosition` property of the SWRevealViewController

```
   if (self.revealViewController().frontViewPosition != FrontViewPosition.Left) { 
   // Do something 
   }
```

If you want to be notified for the menu toggle, implement the following `SWRevealViewControllerDelegate` methods in your delegate. (where you want to observe these changes)

```
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position;
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position;
```

Answer (score 4):

> Swift 3

- Add **SWRevealViewControllerDelegate** to your controller
- Set revealViewControllerDelegate to self in **viewDidLoad()**

  ```
  self.revealViewController().delegate = self
  ```
- Implement this Func with (**didMoveTo**) or the one with (**willMoveTo**) in your viewController

---

```
func revealController(_ revealController: SWRevealViewController!, didMoveTo position: FrontViewPosition) {

    switch position {

    case FrontViewPosition.leftSideMostRemoved:
        print("LeftSideMostRemoved")
        // Left most position, front view is presented left-offseted by rightViewRevealWidth+rigthViewRevealOverdraw

    case FrontViewPosition.leftSideMost:
        print("LeftSideMost")
        // Left position, front view is presented left-offseted by rightViewRevealWidth

    case FrontViewPosition.leftSide:
        print("LeftSide")

        // Center position, rear view is hidden behind front controller
    case FrontViewPosition.left:
        print("Left")
        //Closed
        //0 rotation


        // Right possition, front view is presented right-offseted by rearViewRevealWidth
    case FrontViewPosition.right:
        print("Right")
        //Opened
        //rotated

        // Right most possition, front view is presented right-offseted by rearViewRevealWidth+rearViewRevealOverdraw

    case FrontViewPosition.rightMost:
        print("RightMost")
        // Front controller is removed from view. Animated transitioning from this state will cause the same
        // effect than animating from FrontViewPositionRightMost. Use this instead of FrontViewPositionRightMost when
        // you intent to remove the front controller view from the view hierarchy.

    case FrontViewPosition.rightMostRemoved:
        print("RightMostRemoved")

    }

}
```